# Selenium Web Driver Navigate to Page with POST Request

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to navigate to a page using selenium in python with a post request.

I've got the request working with `seleniumrequests`:

```
response = driver.request('POST','http://example.com', data={"agree": "1"})
```

but it only returns a 200 request string, I'm trying to actually navigate to the page.

Comment: Sounds like you need to sort of agree to a disclaimer or terms of use before navigating the site, right?

Comment: @alecxe Yes that's right, any idea how to submit it?

Comment: I think you may approach it differently. Can you provide the URL to the actual website? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe Can't do that but It's a form with a button without any ID and the post request to access a page.

Comment: Never mind. Here is the idea - if you are using Chrome, install [Edit This Cookie extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en). Open the website, submit the disclaimer/terms of use. Click the Edit this Cookie extension button - do what do you see there? Thanks. I think it's just a cookie that determines whether you accepted the disclaimer or not. Just a theory.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a bit slower, but couldn't you have your driver find the element (check box or whatever it is you have to click saying you agree) and have it click that, then click the agree button to submit it?

So use something like:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver = self.driver
driver.get('http://example.com')
driver.findElementById('idOfCheckBox').click()
```

Then if there is another button to submit that use another `driver.findElementById('idOfButton').click()`